# I need assistance with jQuery ajax dynamic id call ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts2

I have an ajax form use struts2 but it only works with the first link of the links remain inactive.

Code page jsp

```
 <s:iterator value="listlog"  status="incr">
    <tr>                    
       <td  class="data"><s:property value="xxxx"/></td>
       .............................................
       <td  class="data"><s:property value="status"/></td>
       <td  class="data">
          <button id="popModal_ex1" class="btn btn-primary" data-popmodal-bind="#content_blob" ><a class="get_content_blob" id=<s:property value='id'/> >Content</a></button>
           <div style="display:none" ><div  id="content_blob"></div></div>  
     </td>
   </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

code ajax in page

```
<script language='javascript'>

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#popModal_ex1 a').click(function () {
                var idaaa = null;
                idaaa = $(".get_content_blob").attr('id');

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Struts_2/page/msg_detail.action?id=" + idaaa,
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: "",
                    cache: false,
                    timeout: 55000,
                    success: function (data)
                    {
                        $("#content_blob").html(data).fadeIn();
                        return;

                    }
                });                    
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Hug everyone feels concerned and help

Comment: what went wrong here? what help you need?

Comment: use class instead of ID for the same element

Comment: You need a unique ID for each `<div  id="content_blob"></div>`, then you can reference it in the fadeIn

Comment: I understand what you mean, but how to get the id js call is dynamic. can you help me orient. thank you very much

Comment: i try 
 <script language='javascript'>   

            $(document).ready(function () {
               
                $('#popModal_ex1 a ').click(function () {
                    var idaaa = null;
                    idaaa = $(".get_content_blob").attr('id');  
                    
                    $.ajax({
                        
                    });
                });
            });

        </script>
 but idaaa not change

Comment: You need unique id for button also or use class.

Answer (score 0):

Use data-id attribute instead of using anchor tag since you just want to get the id why not put it in data-id, then when your button is clicked, you can now access the id via **this** keyword and get the data-id by dot operator.

```
<s:iterator value="listlog"  status="incr">
     <tr>   
     <td  class="data"><s:property value="xxxx"/></td>
           .............................................
           <td  class="data"><s:property value="status"/></td>                 
                   <td  class="data">
                      <button id="yourUniqueId" class="btn btn-primary popModal_ex" data-popmodal-bind="#content_blob" data-id="<s:property value='id'/>">Content</button>
                       <div style="display:none" ><div  id="content_blob"></div></div>  
          </td>
     </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

Your Ajax Code

```
<script language='javascript'>

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('button.popModal_ex').click(function () {
                var idaaa = null;
                idaaa = $(this).data('id');

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Struts_2/page/msg_detail.action?id=" + idaaa,
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: "",
                    cache: false,
                    timeout: 55000,
                    success: function (data)
                    {
                        $("#content_blob").html(data).fadeIn();
                        return;

                    }
                });                    
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: There is no `a.popModal_ex` in your JSP snippet.